# не работает Yii::app()

Tags: php, yii2

Всем привет, у меня в файле site/config/params.php

```
<?php

return [
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',
];
```

на контроллере и на представление не работает

```
Yii::app();
```

и не могу вызывать `Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'];`

> ```
> Error
>
> Call to undefined method Yii::app()
> ```

Ps. Yii2 basic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Yii2 надо Yii::$app

```
Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'];
```